# ionic firebase get user information from real time database

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I am trying to get user information (for example: username) in my Firebase Database but in `.ts` file, I could not figure out how to code it

I tired using `auth.uid` to get the username from Database but did not work. the below is the code that I have used to save user profile. it works well.

```
this.afAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(auth => {
  let path= 'userProfile'+'/'+ auth.uid;
  this.afDatabase.object(path).set(this.profile);
})
```

But I cannot figure out how to get its info. So in my database, under "userProfile" there is "username". How do I use this logic to get the username? I need to use that `auth.uid` to display the username in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have the following database:

```
userProfile
      userid
        username : peter
```

You can do the following:

```
export class DataComponent implements OnInit{
  ref : any;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
     ref = db.list('/userProfile', ref => ref.orderByKey().equalTo(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)).valueChanges();
    }

  ngOnInit(){
    ref.subscribe(items => {
       console.log(items);  
    });
  }

}
```

Here you query on the node `userId` and then using that node you can retrieve the `username`.

Check the following:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Comment: I get a red line under `auth`. it says cannot find name 'auth'. Is there any way that I can retrieve username from userProfile straight away?

Comment: yes in my code i didnt define `auth`, you need to add `auth` in the constructor and then retrieve the `uid`

Comment: check the edit, and if you want to get the current logged in username then you have to path from the top node to the username node

Comment: yep I can see the uid it just says 0.. so now I have to get username in userProfile/0 (which is the unique user id)/username but I can't figure it out

Comment: In your database you have to add the `auth.uid` as you already wrote in the question, then to retrieve the username, you get the `auth.uid` again as I wrote in the answer

Comment: yes so i can see all the content in my database for a specific user in my console log but the issue is it is showing ALL of them (I also have height, weight etc.) How do I ONLY retrieve username?